# Returning an anonymous type through WCF RIA Service or handling dynamicity w

Tags: .net, wcf-ria-services

i will just come to the point, that WCF RIA Service always returns a strongly type i.e. IEnumerable  IQueryable . Now our scenario is that their are six panes on the client side each containing a datagrid and all these datagrid  contain three level hierarchy i.e

```
Product
   |
   |-Orders
       |        
       |- and so on
```

The thing is that we have a certain table in the database its schema and details are as follows

Table Name PanesInfo

```
ID  PaneName  TableName  TableColomn     Level  Type
1   PaneOne    Products   ProductID        1
2   PaneOne    Products   ProductName      1
3   PaneOne     Orders    OrderID          2
4   PaneOne     Orders    OrderName        2
5   PaneONE     Orders    ORderRef         2
```

SImilarly they will have defined level 2 and this table will contain information for all the panes now the user will have to first query this table to get information  as to what has to be shown in pane one's datagrid at level One LEvel Two and level three so on and so forth (parent child relationship) the asscociation of betweent these levels will also be mentioned here i am not sure how since that has to be discussed with the client now we have tried  a lot of solutions(e.g. xml parsing) please suggest a solution which will have less iterations on the server side since this database is very heavy.

Answer (score 0):

IMO you are thinking too much in terms of data, and not so much interms of customer requirements.   You also have to starting thinking of asynchronous methods, meaning stuff can happen while the screen is updating.  Before your screen is any good to the customer the first grid of Products must be filled.  Selection of a product means you have to fill out Orders, etc. down the chain.

Your first query should be to only retrieve Products.  When the Products arrive on the client, grab the first one, and issue a request to the DB for more info on that Product.  Then raise your properties for the UI to refresh the UI.  While the product grid is refreshing, the DB request is off to gather more info on just that one product (e.g. Orders).  When it (Orders) arrives, it will populate the other grids.  To the user, more then likely, it will LOOK like all the data will arrive at the same time (binding the product grid takes time..)

Each time the client clicks on a another product, you have to go back to the DB to get that data.  Remember, if the client clicks on a previous clicked product, that product data is already on the client side, and you don't have to make the db trip.  How you decide if  you go to the DB or not is logic you have to implement.

If you request data more than once, RIA handles this by merging the data just recieved from the DB into the client side model.  The default mode will not override data that has been changed on the client side.  It will also ignore the data if the data already exits on the client side - which means you made the db trip for nothing.

Remember, this is not client server.  You are transporting data from the server to the client.  There is a client side model, as well as a client-server model on the server side (this is the EF part).  RIA services not only manages the transport of the data, but also gives you a client side model that is identical to a model that is located on the server side.

HTH,
Richard

Answer (score 0):

I belive the question is a bit too vague and it's impossible to define a solution with just that information. 
However, have a look at the IncludeAttribute, it permits to reduce client roundtrip allowing you to serialize an object graph. 
 Of course, that means that you're carrying a lot of data client side. But that's another topic